# Problems with floating table fixed/relative position

Tags: html, css

I have a page with 3 tables inside, one of which is generated from server data and can have any number of rows. The other 2 tables are used to float on top and display buttons and table headers that can be visible at all times. Here is some code:

```
<table style=" position:absolute, top: 110px; z-indez:1; width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> Cart </td>
          <td> Quantity </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table style="margin-top:60px; height:auto; width:100%;">
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.Partial("MoreInformation", item)
     </td>
</tr>
}   
</table>

<table style="position:absolute; bottom:100px; height:70px; width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">
                        <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/Home/Index'">Go Home</button>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is a problem with this setup:
I have a menu on the left side. When I collapse it, the table with MoreInformation follows is smoothly, but the other 2 tables stay fixed on their positions.
How can I make the "floating on top" tables move along with the data table (the table with MoreInformation?

P.S. I have tried placing the 2 tables inside a div, making that div `position:fixed` and the table inside `position:relative` but it does not work.

Comment: why do you want 3 different tables? Why cant you have the header as <th>, the loop to generate the rows from server, and the last row for buttons in the same table? You wouldn't have to style them separately in that case.

Comment: true, but my problem is not this. I want to keep the header table and the footer table fixed position to top and bottom, but relative to left and right.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style=" position:absolute, top: 110px; z-indez:1; width:100%;">
<tr>
        <td>
            <table align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">
                        <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/Home/Index'">Go Home</button>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> Cart </td>
          <td> Quantity </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table style="margin-top:60px; height:auto; width:100%;">
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.Partial("MoreInformation", item)
     </td>
</tr>
}   
</table>
```